# What is the smallest amount of information I need to know all angles and sides of a right-angled triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

If I have two sides of a right-angled triangle, I can calculate the third side. Then I know the tan of the smaller angles and via arctan I can get the angles. (Not sure exactly the formula for arctan, I believe it's an integral.)

I think, if I know 1 side and 1 angle I can get the other information.

Maybe if I know the area?

Is it possible to know all about a right-angled triangle with less information?

Comment: A triangle is determined by three pieces of information. (Not just *any* three, though. For instance, knowing the three angles doesn't do it.) Knowing there's a right angle is one of them, so you need two more.

Comment: If you have a right triangle, and you know one of the *other* angles, then you know all three angles.  Then, if you also know any one of the sides, you can deduce the other two sides.

Comment: You need to know two independent quantities (in addition to right angle). Acute angles are not independent, so you cannot use this pair. Circumcircle radius and hypotenuse length are not independent, so you cannot use this pair.

Comment: This is related to the concept of "degrees of freedom". Just one real number won't ever be enough (unless you use a non-continuous mapping like in a proof $|\mathbb{R}^2| = |\mathbb{R}|$).

Comment: @Blue knowing three angles is not three pieces of (non-trivial information), but just two

Comment: @SBF: *"knowing three angles is not three pieces of (non-trivial information), but just two"* ... I was leaving the contemplation of such nuance to the reader. :)  ... (While I have some comment space, I'll note something else worth contemplating: In *non-Euclidean* geometry, knowing the three angles *is* enough!)

Answer (score 1):

There are five ways to do this. Let's look at the triangle in the picture:

[image]

Considering that we already know one angle of a triangle we only need to know two more pieces of information to construct a triangle. Five ways you could do this:

**$1.$** Knowing side $a$ and angle $\angle{ABC}$,

**$2.$** Knowing side $b$ and angle $\angle{BAC}$,

**$3.$** Knowing side $b$ and side $a$,

**$4.$** Knowing side $a$ and side $c$,

**$5.$** Knowing side $b$ and side $c$.

On the other hand if you know what the area of this triangle is, let's say $Area=\frac{ab}{2}$, then knowing either $a$ or $b$ would be sufficient enough to find all of the information about a triangle.

So in all cases you'd need to more pieces of information (other than it being right-angled,of course) to find a triangle.

Comment: Anything wrong with just knowing c and a?

Comment: In English, $P$ is used for perimeter, so using $A$ for area would be preferable.  Also, the vertices in the angle names should be capitalized so that they cannot be confused with side lengths.

Comment: @SBF thank you I forgot about these two cases two. I added them

Comment: @N.F.Taussig change $P$ to $A$. I think I wrote the angles already like that, but feel free to edit if there is any confusion here.

Comment: @ryang Ok is it fine now that i change $A$ to $Area$? It was an image from online so I didn't want there to be any confusion with angles (this is notation I was taught)

Answer (score 1):

If you know 2 sides, you derive the angles and scale of the Triangle.

If you know 1 angle that is not the angle which is 90 degrees, you can derive the third angle but not the scale of the Triangle.

With 1 angle and 1 side, you can derive another side, and from here the scale and angles follow. To do this, use cosine or sinus.

Let me know if you need a concrete example :).

Comment: Not being a mathematician, an example would be good!

Comment: In triangle ABC, given angle A = 45° and side AB = 10 units, we can find the missing side and angles. Using the cosine function, we find side BC ≈ 7.07 units (BC = 10 * cos(45)). Using the sine function, we find side AC ≈ 7.07 units (AC = 10 * sin(45)). The sum of angles in a triangle is 180°, so angle C = 180 - 45 - 90 = 45°. Therefore, the missing angle is 45°. Thus, the triangle has side lengths AB = 10 units, BC ≈ 7.07 units, and AC ≈ 7.07 units, with angles A = 45°, B = 90°, and C = 45°.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to understand arcsine. I wanted to write a little Python to calculate arcsine when you know the 2 smaller sides. Apparently, they use an approximation of arctan to calculate arcsine. You can find that here: https://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/appendix.htm#algorithms 4 steps, depending on what you've got to start with!